# Http 401 seen in IE/Edge only

Tags: http, internet-explorer, iis, microsoft-edge

That is not happening or not shown in the Consoles when I the app in Chrome or FF. But in IE/Edge it looks like this:

[image]

That's happening if an HTTP request is placed after a short while of idling. Just around 2 min or so.

Any idea why am I getting 401 first and then 200?

Comment: That's exactly the so called challenged based authentication, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2018/02/14/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/ Without such 401, the web browser won't send user credentials and the server won't be able to authenticate the users. Of course, you can change browser settings so that they send credentials in the very first request to suppress such 401 responses.

Comment: Agree with what Lex Li says, the article has shown clearly why http 401 shows up. IE and Edge *don't send any credentials on their first request for a resource. This means that first request is anonymous. This anonymous request, when Windows Auth is enabled and Anonymous Auth is disabled in IIS, results in an HTTP 401 status.* You could also refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2014/02/11/iis-how-to-reduce-multiple-authentication-or-multiple-401-while-using-kerberos-for-authentication/) about reducing 401 when using Kerberos for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation. Does that mean Chrome and FF send credentials on the first request?

Comment: It might be, different browsers have different default behaviors, they're by-design. I think we need to research deeper.